# User Defined function is not responding in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I try some code in R, but the use defined function could not respond.

```
factor_func_gender<-function(x){
  x$Gender=factor(x$Gender,labels = c(0,1))
}


mixed_data=my_data$depressiondummy[2:30]
factor_func_gender(mixed_data)
```

I run this code. But it is not showed any error. What can i do?

Comment: 1) Your function must return something, it will be the value of the last instruction. Example `x` if you want to return the df or `x$Gender` if you want to return the vector. 2) You must assign the return value, `mixed_data <- factor_func_gender(mixed_data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just typing up an answer when @RuiBarradas beat me to it.

For what it's worth, and to reiterate, the two issues with your code are

1. `factor_func_gender` does not return the modified `data.frame`.
2. When calling `factor_func_gender` you are not storing the output object of the function (i.e. your modified `data.frame`) in a new variable.

Here is what you can do to fix those issues:

```
# Let's generate some sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(
    Gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each = 5),
    Value = runif(10));

# Define the function that returns a data.frame
factor_func_gender <- function(x) {
      x$Gender <- factor(x$Gender, labels = c(0, 1));
      return(x);    # Return the dataframe
}

# Apply the function to a data.frame and store output in new data.frame
df.new <- factor_func_gender(df);
str(df.new);
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
# $ Value : num  0.924 0.537 0.469 0.289 0.77 ...
```